# Entity Framework Context per request in ASP.NET and Multi Threading

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, entity-framework, httpcontext

My application is in ASP.NET MVC 4.

I'm using BDContext per request, as recommended in many questions here.

I have:

```
public static class ContextPerRequest {
    private const string myDbPerRequestContext = "dbGeTraining_";

    public static DbGesForma_v2 db {
        get {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(myDbPerRequestContext + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x") + Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString())) {
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(myDbPerRequestContext + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x") + Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString(), new DbGesForma_v2());
            }

            return HttpContext.Current.Items[myDbPerRequestContext + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x") + Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString()] as DbGesForma_v2;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called automatically on Application_EndRequest()
    /// </summary>
    public static void DisposeDbContextPerRequest() {
        // Getting dbContext directly to avoid creating it in case it was not already created.
        var entityContext = HttpContext.Current.Items[myDbPerRequestContext + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x") + Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString()] as DbGesForma_v2;
        if (entityContext != null) {
            entityContext.Dispose();
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(myDbPerRequestContext + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x") + Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And I dispose it in Application_EndRequest() method. This approach worked well for a long time.

Now I'm trying to implement something with asynchronous tasks like this:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                DoSomething();
            });
```

This brings some problems.

1. HttpContext is null in subthreads, and is used in the key of the context.
2. Even if I would be able to pass httpcontext or null check it, if a subthread takes longer to run than the request itself, it would be disposed before the thread finishes, which would be problematic.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of ASP.NET you use. Anyway, ASP.NET MVC (also WebAPI) has DependencyResolver which support those 'per-request' instance.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Also, I recommend you to use DI framework with DependencyResolver, rather than implement per-request instance factory (or something like that). Most of well-known DI frameworks are support integration with ASP.NET.

For instance;

- [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)
- [Autofac](http://autofac.org/)
- [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html)
- and many others

Comment: I didn't even know about that. I'll read more in depht about that. But the project is already really big (2 years, 2 developers full time developing), It would be a massive change to use this, or do you think it's doable?

Comment: How is the dispose of the context handled?

Comment: It depends on DI framework, but as far I know, above all frameworks support auto-disposing feature when the scope(HttpRequest in this case) is completed. You can also write implicit disposing code too.

Here's SimpleInjector docs for example; https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#per-web-request

Answer (score 0):

I've found a less intrusive solution. (I know, Gongdo Gong solution is much better, but requires a lot of changes in an ongoing project)

When I call the async task I pass through the HttpContext, and at the end I dispose the Context.

Like this:

```
      System.Web.HttpContext htcont = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current = htcont;
                DoSomething();
                ContextPerRequest.DisposeDbContextPerRequest();
       });
```

This way HttpContext is usable inside the subthread and the context gets disposed at the end of the job.